# How to get vimchat to work in linux

Tags: vim

I added

```
Bundle 'throughnothing/vimchat'
```

to my `~/.vimrc` file and ran `:PluginInstall`. That all ran fine, then I added an account and password to the `~/.vim/Bundle/vimchat/config` file like this:

```
user@domain = password
```

When I run `vim` and type `:VimChat` (after restarting) I get this message:

```
E492: Not an editor command: VimChat
```

Clearly the installation somehow failed, but I'm a bit at a loss on how to diagnose this. The installation seemed to go fine!

I'm using `vim 7.4`

Comment: Issue started here: https://github.com/throughnothing/vimchat/issues/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a general installation issue, nothing plugin-specific (for which you should open an issue against the plugin). Ensure that the plugin's bundle directory is contained in `'runtimepath'`, and that the `plugin/vimchat.vim` file is actually sourced:

```
:set rtp?
:scriptnames
```

Comment: I can see `vimchat` in the runtime path as well as the `vimchat.vim` file when I type `:scriptnames`. I'll open an issue.